# How to pre-select value of ion-select AND store the selected value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is my HTML file

```
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Main Store Name</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)] = "SelectedMainStore" 
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
        value="{{SelectedMainStore}}" [compareWith] = "compareWith" >

            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let mainStore of MainStoreArray" 
        value="{{mainStore.mainStoreId}}">
              {{mainStore.mainStoreName}}</ion-select-option>

          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

I am able to pre-select the value of the Select by making use of the "[compareWith]" and "value = '{{SelectedMainStore}}' ". My plan was then to make use of [(ngModel)] to save whatever option is chosen. But when I add [(ngModel)] then the {{mainStore.mainStoreName}} no longer appears by the ion-select.

This is what the [compareWith] looks like :

```
compareWithFn(o1, o2) {
  return o1 === o2;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ion-select-option if you provide value like below

```
value="{{mainStore.mainStoreId}}"
```

then this value will be consider as string and default value of SelectedMainStore is number that's why it's not working as you are expecting.

Please user value as angular tab like below.

```
[value]="mainStore.mainStoreId"
```

Now it will work. Below given full html code for ion-select.

```
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectedMainStore" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let mainStore of MainStoreArray" [value]="mainStore.mainStoreId">
          {{mainStore.mainStoreName}}</ion-select-option>

      </ion-select>
```